# Smart pointers in C++ with shared object-validation

Tags: c++, smart-pointers

I need smart pointer class or template, which can invalidate it's referencing object after 'delete' happens. Key point is to make pointer usable in debug for multy-thread apps.

Here is an example, just pseudocode:

```
void foo1(smart_ptr<myclass> ptr)
{
    //some code
    delete ptr;
    //some other code
}

void foo2(smart_ptr<myclass> ptr)
{
    //some code
    function_wich_uses_ptr(ptr);
    //some other code
}


int main()
{
    myclass val = new myclass();
    smart_ptr<myclass> ptr(&val);
    //somehow make a copy of ptr
    smart_ptr<myclass> ptr2(ptr);
    //some code
    thread_start(foo1, ptr);
    thread_start(foo2, ptr2);
    //
    return 0;
}
```

So, I need foo2 somehow to track if foo1 has already deleted object referenced to ptr.
In general - after anyone of 'living' smart pointers to a single obect deletes that object, all the other pointers to the same object should somehow 'feel' it and set it's own value to NULL.

**UPD** my bad, example was incorrect

Answer (score 3):

You are looking for a non-owning smart-pointer. This is exactly what [`boost::weak_ptr`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/smart_ptr/weak_ptr.htm) does.

Comment: Not exactly, weak_ptr can'be crated from a raw pointer, and thus there should be 'master' shared_ptr, but that means this pointers will not have same functionality. Possibility of deletion is required from each copy of a pointer, so that's another reason not to use weak_ptr.

Comment: @MaximEfimov: I am not sure I understand your scenario. In the example you give, why can't you just pass `val` by reference to the threads and delete it after both threads have finished?

Comment: I fixed code example, it wasn't right. Anyway, I think more description is needed. This pointer is requiered for debuggin multy-thread apps. So - it's running, for example, 10 threads doing some job with the same object. One thread somehow ended and deleted the object, but the rest are still working with invalid pointers to nonexisting object. I need pointer, which can 'inform' other pointers to the object, that it has been deleted, as they should make themeselves NULL. Hope it gives more clarity.

Comment: @Maxim: None of your threads should delete the object if others are still using it. You should only delete the object after all thread have finished. A normal `shared_ptr` will take care of that perfectly. Why do you want one thread to delete the object explicitly?

Comment: The only point of such a pointer - is debug. The situation I described is totaly bad, that's true. But step-by-step debug is quiet challanging while doing with multy-thread application - so such pointer would help to understand where is the error in a programm.

Comment: @MaximEfimov: You could declare a destructor for your class and set a breakpoint on it.

Comment: Well, yes it is a solution. But I still have to make such a pointer - it's on the tasks of my C++ classes in Univercity.